# Android Error Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-espresso

I've encountered this problem on Android Espresso testing. But this works well when run/compile. I know this error has several threads but I have not been able to find a fix that matches my situation. I am currently dealing with a

> "java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class
>   resolved to unexpected implementation".

I've already add

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
   exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

But it's still not working. Can somebody help me with this problem. Thanks.

**Here is my dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    /*Android Testing*/
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'

    /*Showcase view for Facebook Intregation*/
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    /*Showcase view for SwipeRefresh*/
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
    /*Multidex*/
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    /*Crashlytics*/
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a long time, I find a solution for gradle 1.5. 
I move to Robotium and try this code.
But I think this will work too with Espresso.
Here it is,

```
androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include:'robotium-solo-5.3.0.jar')
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex' }

project.configurations.all { config ->
    if (config.name.contains("AndroidTest")) {
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.name == "multidex") {
                details.useTarget("de.felixschulze.teamcity:teamcity-status-message-helper:1.2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
   exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

with

```
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
```

Hope it help

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not working. I use Genymotion emulator. Is there any particular way to handle it?